# inbuilt admin page in django 1.10 python 3.4 with peewee and pymysql throwing error

Tags: python, django, peewee, pymysql

I am using django for my application. To create Builtin admin page i configured some files, which are as follows

**1**. to connect with mysql I have used `pymysql`, for configuring in project's  `1__init__.py` file

```
try:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except:
    pass
```

**2**. In project's `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from story import views
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),
      url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
]
```

**3**. In project's `settings.py` introduced my app in `INSTALLED_APPS`

**4**. In app of project's `models.py`

```
from peewee import *
database = MySQLDatabase('mysite', **{'user': 'root', 'password': 'pwd'})
class UnknownField(object):
       def \__init__(self, *_, **__):
         pass
class BaseModel(Model):
      class Meta:<br/>
           database = database

class User(BaseModel):
      name = CharField(null=True)

class Meta:
              db_table = 'user'
```

This code is generated through `pwiz` command of peewee.

**5**. in app of project's `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from story.models import User
admin.site.register(User)
```

when I run `/>python manage.py runserver` command gives me error `"AttributeError: 'ModelOptions' object has no attribute 'abstract'"`

Please suggest me what could be the possible solution. 
 **Thanks**

Comment: Can you repaste your code with 4 leading spaces? Somehow you have got `&nbsp;` and `<br>` all over the place so it's a lot of work to clean up without the original source.

Comment: Why are you mixing peewee and Django? Django has its own ORM, there's no reason to think the admin would work with peewee.

Comment: Could you also paste the entire error stacktrace?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I tried it with 4 spaces but it did not take it, that's why I used &nbsp;

Comment: @DanielRoseman because it is light weight alternative of django ORM and along with it easy to use and consistent api.

Comment: But what makes you think you can use peewee models in Django's admin?